# Timer flash to show something at the right time

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, video, timer

I want to make a timer that will show text at my panelText (dynamic text box) at specific time, actually I have a video that I want to have subtitles, and I want to use timer, my video is 3 minutes and 37 second long, and I have script that I want to show at some time, example at 1 minute 0 seconds it will show the text "hello, this is my video to learn about solar system" in my panelText, and at 2 minute I want to show text "There are 8 planets in our solar system", something like that. For information, I'm using flvPlayback to play the video and load the external video.

An example from my code:

```
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(217000);
var time = 0;
myTimer.start()
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,timerHandle);

function timerHandle(event:TimerEvent){
    if(myTimer == 120000)
    {
        panelText.text="There's 8 planets in our solar system";
    }
```

and i got error 1176: Comparison between a value with static type flash.utils:Timer and a possibly unrelated type int. can someone help me?, i'm sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `FLVPlayback`'s [`addASCuePoint()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/video/FLVPlayback.html#addASCuePoint()) function to make precise actions when your FLVPlayback fideo is playing. You use this function to set up whatever points you want to display custom subtitles, there can be as many of these as you want, then you listen for `MetadataEvent.CUE_POINT` event on your `FLVPlayback` instance, and process the cue point in order to display the associated subtitle. Note though, you will have to separately parse subtitle expiration, or assign a cue point to remove the displayed subtitle several seconds past the displaying cue point. Although it will be better if you will be able to add subtitles directly on the video, so that seeking through your video will not require handling of misaligned subtitles. Still, it's doable with pure AS3 code, if you would also listen to `VideoEvent.FAST_FORWARD` and `VideoEvent.REWIND` events to handle user interaction with playback and display corresponding subtitle by calling `findNearestCuePoint()` to find the closest earlier subtitle-enabled cue point.

An example of adding a cue point:

```
flv.addASCuePoint(0.1,"1",{text:"Subtitle one"});
flv.addASCuePoint(6.8,"2",{text:"Subtitle two"});
flv.addASCuePoint(11.8,"2 hide",{text:""}); // remove old subtitle
flv.addASCuePoint(120.0,"3",{text:"There are 8 planets in our solar system"});
```

Note that each call returns an `Object`, which is also returned whenever a `MetadataEvent.CUE_POINT` event is dispatched. This has a `parameters` sub-object that you have passed into `addASCuePoint` as third parameter, which you then parse and take actions depending on what's in there. Here, I've placed a single field "text" into each of the parameter objects, which should be the text to display as subtitles. So, then you listen to the cue point event and take actions, like this:

```
flv.addEventListener(MetadataEvent.CUE_POINT,cueHandler); 
// do this only once, a listener does not need to be added per cue point
function cueHandler(e:MetadataEvent):void {
    var cuepoint:Object=e.info;
    if (cuepoint.parameters) {
        panelText.text=cuepoint.parameters.text;
    } else {
        // DEBUG here
    }
}
```

In case of seeking, you listen for FF and rewind events with a function that will call `findNearestCuePoint()`, retrieve its `parameters.text` and place that text into your text field.

Comment: right now, i'm trying your way Vesper, but i don't really know how to use MetadataEvent.CUE_POINT, i have already put my code into addASCuePoint(), but i don't really know how to use that code, because i'm still a newbie , this is my code, myVideo.addASCuePoint(0.1, panelText.text="tryA"); 
myVideo.addASCuePoint(6.8,panelText.text="tryB"); 
myVideo.addASCuePoint(12.9, panelText.text="tryC");

Comment: It's said you put there an `Object` instead of code into `addASCuePoint`, and you also miss a `name` parameter.

Comment: Minor comment, could you please link the English documentation to addAsCuePoint? Currently you're linking to the Russian documentation.

Comment: @DodgerThud Oops. Fixed the link.

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstood the usage of the `Timer` class.

`var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(n)` means that the Timer will always "tick" at the specified interval `n`, in your case every 217000 milliseconds (217 seconds).

This might not be the best solution, but it'll show you how you can use the timer class for a scenario such as yours.

```
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000); //a timer that will tick every second
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerHandler);
myTimer.start(); //you should set up your listener before you start the timer

function timerHandler(event:TimerEvent):void{
    //myTimer.currentCount will tell you how many times your Timer has ticked
    //every tick, in this scenario, represents exactly one second, because we initialized the Timer with 1000 milliseconds
    //so, if you want to show some text 86 seconds after the video has started, you could do:

    if(myTimer.currentCount == 86){
         panelText.text = "We're 86 seconds into the video";
    }else if(myTimer.currentCount == 217){
         //after reading your code it seems like you intended to let the timer only run 217 seconds, because that's the length of your video
         //my proposed solution could also handle this, in this else if clause

         myTimer.stop();
         myTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerHandler);
         myTimer = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: A quick question: What will happen if the FLVPlayback will be paused?

Comment: @Vesper Of course, didn't think about this scenario. But pausing the timer when you pause the video shouldn't be too hard. Thanks for the catch, quick and dirty solutions are not always the best :D

Comment: i think it didn't work for me, i was trying to use your code and didn't work, i don't know why, my panelText didn't change into a text that i want to show, it just can't change, i'm trying to input manually in my panelText to testify the code, but when the code run, it didn't work, and my panelText didn't change

Comment: @japjay that's strange, could you show me how you implemented my code? (by editing your question, please.)

Comment: @japjay "Didn't work" is not the right way to say something in the realm of programming. You should add traces to whatever portions of code to check if they have been reached at all, and if not, you'll have to report something better than this. Do debug the code yourself first, and do not blindly copy&paste code expecting it will "work" as you want it.

Comment: i almost forgot, that i have quick links to go at the specific time in my video, i'm using video.seek(time); to go at the time that i want, can it sync with my quick link?(timer) or you have any solution?

Comment: @japjay Hmm, no, with seeking within the video, my solution won't work, or rather would be too complicated to keep track of. For a more stable solution, see Vespers answers, since Cuepoints are usually the way to go.

Comment: var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000);
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerHandler);
myTimer.start();
panelGambaran.text ="";
function timerHandler(event:TimerEvent):void{
    if(myTimer.currentCount == 0){
        panelText.text ="Our solar system";
    }
 else if(myTimer.currentCount == 6.8){
  panelText.text ="the sky is so beautiful";
 }
 else if(myTimer.currentCount == 217){
         myTimer.stop();
         myTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerHandler);
         myTimer = null;
    }
} i got no error,the timer work, but my panelText didn't change, i don't know why

Comment: currentCount will never be 0, it will be at least one, because for the function to be called, at least one tick has to have happened. Also, currentCount is an integer, you cannot compare it to decimals such as 6.8. (another weakness of the solution, you can work around it with setting the Timer delay to 100 ms, but that could get confusing).

Answer (score 0):

The error is right.you are comparing a timer with a number!!.
fixed part of code:

```
if(myTimer.currentCount==120000){
  panelText.text="There's 8 planets in our solar system";
}
```

and your timer constructor is wrong!the first argument is delay and next is repeat count.
the fixed code:

```
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(100,2170);
var time = 0;
myTimer.start()
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,timerHandle);

function timerHandle(event:TimerEvent){
  if(myTimer.currentCount == 1200)
  {
    panelText.text="There's 8 planets in our solar system";
}
```

in this code, our timer ticked at every 0.1 second(100 miliseconds) and is ticked 2170 times. so, to set your text, you must put a zero after your desired second.

hope this helps :)

Comment: It's the other way around, it will tick every 2170ms and is repeated 100 times. [According to the Documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html#Timer())

Comment: still didn't work, timer does work, but my panelText didn't change

Comment: that works for me.maybe that's because Timer class isn't exact.it has a delay.did you wait for about 10 seconds after reaching to 120?and for being faster,set the 120 to a lesser time to avoid waiting a lot for your testing.